# ArduinoISP not responding

Tags: arduino, atmega, avrdude

So I'm trying to upload sketches to an ATmega328 chip via my Arduino as an ISP. I've successfully been able to burn the bootloader, but when I try to upload sketches, I'm presented with this error.

```
avrdude: Version 5.11, compiled on Sep  2 2011 at 18:52:52
         Copyright (c) 2000-2005 Brian Dean, http://www.bdmicro.com/
         Copyright (c) 2007-2009 Joerg Wunsch

         System wide configuration file is  "/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Resources/Java/hardware/tools/avr/etc/avrdud e.conf"
        User configuration file is "/Users/garrettoelze/.avrduderc"
        User configuration file does not exist or is not a regular file,    skipping

        Using Port                    : /dev/tty.usbmodem1a21
        Using Programmer              : stk500v1
        Overriding Baud Rate          : 57600
avrdude: Send: 0 [30]   [20] 
avrdude: Send: 0 [30]   [20] 
avrdude: Send: 0 [30]   [20] 
avrdude: ser_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding

avrdude done.  Thank you.
```

I've been looking all over the internet and I can't find a solution that works. Any answers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm assuming you've removed the avrISP and are talking to the burned chip directly. This tells me that you, in fact, did not succesfully burn the bootloader. Where did you get the .hex? did you compile it yourself? Did you set the fuses right as well?

Comment: @crasic, I successfully burned the bootloader via the ArduinoISP. The hex was compiled in the Arduino IDE. I'm using the programmer fuse configuration that I downloaded from arduino.cc ("Breadboard.zip").